# RavenDB Disallow Delete if Not in Use

Tags: ravendb

I just had a user delete two documents in my Raven DB. That caused issues as those documents were referenced by other documents. I know that Raven has a bundle to cascade delete, but I'm more looking for a way to disallow a delete if it's referenced by another document. Is there a standard RavenDB way of doing this? Or do I need to loop through all of my documents to check if the document is referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bob, unfortunately there's no standard way to do this, because the database itself doesn't know what a relation between documents is.

So, if you want to prevent user from deleting these documents then yes, you have to check yourself if there are any other documents referencing the current one.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Do you know if I'll have to do many separate queries, for each document type I have? Or is there one query that could return any instance of the document I want to delete?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand this question. Can you please try to explain?

Comment: Can I do *one* query to see if a certain document ID exists more than once? If there is more than one, then I know it is referenced by another document. Otherwise, I would have to do separate queries (Query<DocType>) for each document type to see if they reference the document I want to delete.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel said, RavenDB doesn't know about associatations between docs, so it can't do this out of the box.

However you could implement your own bundle and use the [delete trigger](http://old.ravendb.net/documentation/triggers/read) functionality to veto/allow the delete to succeed.

If you want to go down this route, take a look at how the [Cascading Delete](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/tree/master/Bundles/Raven.Bundles.CascadeDelete) bundle is implemented. You would just need to do the opposite.

Comment: Ooooooh... that might be an interesting opportunity to make an improvement. I'll have to check into that. Thanks!

Comment: That delete trigger link is broken. Do you have a better one?

Comment: I think the major piece of doing this is to find all of the documents that reference the document to be deleted. In fact, if *any* document references the document to be deleted, then I want to throw an exception. In the link you provided, it looks like the referenced documents are found this way: var documentsToDelete = document.Metadata.Value<RavenJArray>(MetadataKeys.DocumentsToCascadeDelete); Does that make sense to you? I tried that in my code and got null.